# How to change output device for backups

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I want to use a new, external drive for my backups.  I believe I'm using deja-dup now, but I'm not 100% sure:
[image: Déjà-dup screen]

I cannot figure out how to change the name of the Storage Location for the backups so that it can start using a different external drive to store the backups.  Where do I go to change it?  The System Settings/Backups feature shows the name of the Storage Location but does not seem to provide a place to change it.

The picture of the Storage Location window shows the name of the external drive I was using,
[image: Déjà-dup settings]

but one cannot write in that field and if I click on the arrow at the right hand end, it gives a list of options but no place to type in the drive name.  The Folder part shows the directory on the drive where I had it put the backups.  But something has failed on that drive and it doesn't actually make backups anymore.  I have no idea where to start over setting up backups.

*How do I proceed?*

Comment: Click on storage location and change from there, please post an image of the backup settings

Comment: Please [edit] your question, Insert the new drive, go to a terminal and type: `mount` and provide the output as text in your question.  Then run this command `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.DejaDup` and provide the output to that too.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. It seems to be a UI bug that storage location can't be set.

A workaround is to open [dconf-editor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf), navigate to org/gnome/deja-dupe/drive and edit the drive name and UUID. You can find the UUID by running `blkid`.