# How do you change the backup location on Deja-Dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I want to switch the Deja Dup backup location to a different drive but can't see an option to do this. How can it be done?

Is there a way to manage the utility other than the UI, which seems to be next to useless afaics? I'm looking at the interface now which tells me 'Next backup is today' but the 'Back up now' is greyed out as is the Restore button.

The storage button shows options 'Google, Next Cloud, Network Server, XXXXX, Local Folder' where XXXXX is the current set drive. And that's it in terms of options.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/969259/how-to-change-output-device-for-backups claims its a bug and has a manual edit of dconf as a method

Comment: Thanks! Jeez - this thing's really ready for mass usage! I guess Time Machine is safe for now. I'll try later and update here.

Answer (score 0):

If you open "Local Folder" there is a button with "Choose directory" (or similar, my OS language is German so I'm not exactly sure what it is in the English version). If you click on this button you can choose any directory to be the saving location on any drive, including attached USB drives, on your machine